Visibilitychange listener that works when switching workspaces
I have an iframe inside a HTML page.html that loads iframe.html. The iframe.html code has an event Listener for the iframe content to be reloaded when the document becomes visible (e.g., when bringing a tab forward):
window.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
    if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') refreshImgArray(); 
});

However, this listener is not triggered when the window is in other "virtual workspace" (e.g., the different workspaces provided by Gnome and KDE), and I switch to the workspace containing the browser, despite the fact that the whole workspace became visible and not just the browser window.
Which is the proper javascript event listener to include in iframe.html for it to be reloaded when the browser window becomes visible after switching workspaces?

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. As it is, your question is unclear, particularly your use of "workspace" within the browser.

Edited, hopefully more clear now.

Your question is still missing a [mre]. What does "switching workspaces" consist of? Browsing to another site in the iframe?

"switching workspaces" has nothing to do with other sites, or with a minimal reproducible example. It refers to the usual switch between workspaces inside Linux window managers. There is no need for any example: Which is the event listener that detects workspace change? If this is possible at all, that is...

I can't find a site that discusses this explicitly, but Google's AI claims "changing Gnome workspaces does not trigger a browser event in JavaScript."

MMmmm... I see... Maybe I should check for window focus then. Thanks!
